# QNetworkRequest not working

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I have a Qt application that I'm deploying with Qt 4.8.1 under Windows 7 x64 SP1, but compiled with 32 bit. The application uses `QNetworkAccessManager`, `QNetworkRequest`, and `QNetworkReply` to communicate over HTTPS to a server.  I have successfully tested this connection on five different machines.  On the sixth machine I went to test this on the connection failed with a `QNetworkReply::NetworkError UnknownNetworkError`. This machine can go to the URL in a web browser and that communication works fine.  Additionally I was able to use a different computer on the same network and successfully make the connection with my application. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this behavior?  Also, I saw this behavior with Qt version 4.7.4 as well as 4.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an SSL problem.  Apparently Qt requires the OpenSSL dlls.  Once I included those everything worked fine.

Comment: Where are OpenSSL dlls for Win7?